# Can we compare +inf.0 in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'd tried to compare `+inf.0` in Racket, for example:

```
> (eq? +inf.0 +inf.0)
#t
> (+ +inf.0 2)
+inf.0
```

But:

```
> (> (+ +inf.0 2) +inf.0)
#f
> (eq? (+ +inf.0 2) +inf.0)
#f
> (< (+ +inf.0 2) +inf.0)
#f
```

I was wondering if maybe we could compare the positive infinity number in this way?

Comment: Use `=` instead of `eq?` to compare numbers and you will get reasonable results (in general, avoid `eq?` unless you are sure it’s what you want; use `equal?` for most things and use `=` for numbers). Of course, `(+ +inf.0 2)` is just `+inf.0`.

Comment: @AlexisKing, looks like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem here is that you are using the wrong types of equality. Racket's equality checking is a bit complex, and is mostly just residual remnants of its Scheme heritage. Here are the four types, and when you should use them:

- [`=`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=%3D#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._~3d%29%29) Use this for numbers. Such as `(= 5 5)`
- [`eq?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=eq%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eq~3f%29%29) Use this for pointer equality. More or less, when two things are pointing to the same location in memory. You generally don't want to use this unless you are comparing symbols, or if you are comparing two variables to see if they are pointing to the same location in memory. This is similar to `==` in Java. (But unlike `==` in java, do not use it to compare numbers, use `=` for that.)
- [`eqv?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=eqv%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eqv~3f%29%29) Don't use this. I'm sure someone knows what it's used for, but that person is not me. It's there because it used to be used for something, but it's not really any more.
- [`equal?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=equal%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._equal~3f%29%29) Use this for deep object equality. It will look at the elements of structs to see if they are equal (if they are transparent anyway). In fact, structs [can even declare a method](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=g#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._gen~3aequal%2Bhash%29%29) that `equal?` uses to determin equality. This is very similar to `.equals()` in Java. If two things are `eq?`, they are `equal?`.

So, with that out of the way, there are some tricky edge cases to deal with. Usually involving `NaN` and `+inf.0`. As you've seen here, `+inf.0` is not `eq?` to itself, however, it is `=` to itself.

```
(= +inf.0 +inf.0)   ;; => #t
(eq? +inf.0 +inf.0) ;; => #f
```

Also, one other caveat, not all objects can be compared deeply. One example of this is closures. In those cases, `equal?` will do pointer equality like `eq?`.

```
(equal? (lambda (x) 5) (lambda (x) 5)) ;; => #f
(let ([a (lambda (x) 5)])
  (equal? a a)) ;; => #t
```

Comment: I think that saying “most, but not all, uses of number equality will be covered by `eq?`” is dangerous. I would avoid `eq?` for *everything* except symbol equality, myself. And even then, I would probably just use `equal?` for consistency. The equivalence function soup is one of the more unnecessarily confusing things about Racket’s roots in Scheme, and I think it is mostly unnecessary. Use `equal?` for everything and it will do the right thing all the time... except for numbers. Use `=` for that. (I consider this to be poor behavior, though—maybe someday it can be fixed.)

Comment: I would be happy to reword that sentence. But some of what you said there is not true, `eq?` should also be used for pointer equality. This is important if you want two variables to only be equal if they are pointing to the same struct in memory, for example, if you are modeling hygiene.

Comment: So, I modified the answer. @AlexisKing, are you happier with that one?

Comment: Yes, that’s nicer. I take your point, but I think almost all of the time, pointer equality is an implementation detail.

Comment: I understand that thought. But memory location is not just an implementation detail once effects are involved. For example, if you mutate a struct, and you have two variables aliasing the struct, then both of them will appear to have their values changed. (Unless you use R's semantics which are copy on write, in which case memory location is just an implementation detail.)

Comment: But sure, if there was no aliasing, I could see a good argument for memory location being just an implementation detail.